# Qt: Invoke a function with arguments in UI thread

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

I have a background thread performing a task and once done, UI should be updated. To update UI, I need the UI thread to execute my function which has the code to update UI.

Qt has [QMetaObject::invokeMethod((QObject *context, Functor function, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection, FunctorReturnType *ret = nullptr)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-4) method. According to documentation, Qt invokes a functor or a function in the thread that created the context pointer. But it can also be achieved using a lambda (as shown below).

```
// QtApplicationWrapper::sApp is of type QGuiApplication
// pFunc - pointer to a function
// pFuncParms - argument of type void *
QMetaObject::invokeMethod (QtApplicationWrapper::sApp,
                           [=] {
                               pFunc (pFuncParms);
                           },
                           Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

The above code works. But let's say I don't want to use a lambda or a functor.

pFunc could be directly passed to QMetaObject::invokeMethod as shown below:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod (QtApplicationWrapper::sApp,
                           pFunc,
                           Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

But I don't know how to pass arguments. The above code only works for a function taking no args.

How can I have pFunc invoked with its arguments in UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

QMetaObject has multiple overloads, as documented at `https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html`.

One of those overloads is `bool invokeMethod(QObject *obj, const char *member, Qt::ConnectionType type, Args &&... args)`, which takes an arbitrary number of arguments and may be called like this: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "performAction", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection, Q_ARG(std::string&, result), Q_ARG(std::string, action), Q_ARG(std::string, signal), Q_ARG(std::string, param));`

Please note that, when passing pointers or references, that you must either use a blocking connection or ensure some other way that the information you are passing is still valid when the message is actually executed.

The first two parameters are the most important piece information for this overload. The first one tells Qt, in which class to look for the function specified in the second parameter (which is a string, not a function pointer).

If you want to use 'proper notation', I strongly recommend using either a lambda or `std::bind`.

Comment: I'm aware of the overloads - like [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-2) one. But it's not mentioned in the documentation that the passed method will get invoked in main thread. The object is used to invoke the method.. that's all. Those overloads whose first object is a context pointer, they get invoked in main thread if I pass an object that's created in main thread. Among these, I couldn't find an overload which takes a function and a pointer.

Comment: You are correct, @NightFuryLxD. Whether the method will be invoked on the main thread fully depends on the thread context of the QObject you pass as the first parameter. As such, if you want to invoke a method on the GUI thread, invoking a method of a GUI class is a very good guess.